# Government spending and revenue statistics

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, statistics

I am looking for thorough statistics of budgetary spending and revenues by category for approx all oecd countries. If not for all oecd i will be happy to have data only for Switzerland. I am interested in time period from 1995 to 2013. Unfortunately i am not able to find comprehensive source for those data. Could you give me some hints with regard to possible source of such data?

EDIT: Precisely i am looking for something ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_budget_of_Switzerland ) like 4.1.  i.e. this table (but for both expenditures and revenues) with example budget but i want to have this year by year.

Comment: Same question here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/which-all-governments-publish-their-ledgers-and-accounts

Comment: that's said that there is no one place with data of this type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want data for OECD countries have a look at the OECD's Statistics portal. You will find the data in the "National Accounts" as section as well as in the "Public Sector, Taxation and Market Regulation"

As an alternative or as a complement you can also have a look at the [Eurostat database on Government Statistics](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/government-finance-statistics/data/database). They do have data for Switzerland as well as for many OECD countries.

Finally, as you seem to be focussed on Switzerland, you can also try to find the data via the Federal Statistical Office.

You can obtain time series by following the links in the "additional information" column.

Comment: But on after the selection of switzerland on oecd website i am left with a blank page...

Comment: i've found data on eurostat, not only switzerland because i want to have some kind of comparison between different countries

Answer (score 2):

My usual go-to is FRED: http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/search?st=government+spending

They normally have much more data then any other site I have managed to find.